# How to write a zoomable voronoi diagram using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, voronoi

I wanna write a zoomable voronoi diagram using d3.js. But why only the sites are zoomable but the links and polygons are not zoomable.

My code is shown below. And I referred to this [voronoi example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060366) and [zoom scatter diagram example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680957).

PS. (I removed the unnecessary onmove action of the original voronoi example)

Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.links {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-opacity: 0.2;
}

.polygons {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
}

.sites {
  fill: #000;
  stroke: #fff;
}


</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var sites = d3.range(100)
    .map(function(d) { return [Math.random() * width, Math.random() * height]; });

var voronoi = d3.voronoi()
    .extent([[-1, -1], [width + 1, height + 1]]);

var polygon = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "polygons")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(voronoi.polygons(sites))
  .enter().append("path")
    .call(redrawPolygon);

var link = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "links")
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(voronoi.links(sites))
  .enter().append("line")
    .call(redrawLink);

var site = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "sites")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(sites)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 2.5)
    .call(redrawSite)
    .attr("transform", transform(d3.zoomIdentity));

svg.call(d3.zoom()
          .scaleExtent([1,8])
          .on("zoom",zoom));

function zoom() {
  site.attr("transform", transform(d3.event.transform));
  redraw();
}

function transform(t) {
  return function(d) {
    return "translate(" + t.apply(d) + ")";
  };
}


function redraw() {
  var diagram = voronoi(sites);
  polygon = polygon.data(diagram.polygons()).call(redrawPolygon);
  link = link.data(diagram.links()), link.exit().remove();
  link = link.enter().append("line").merge(link).call(redrawLink);
  site = site.data(sites).call(redrawSite);
}

function redrawPolygon(polygon) {
  polygon
      .attr("d", function(d) { return d ? "M" + d.join("L") + "Z" : null; });
}

function redrawLink(link) {
  link
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source[0]; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source[1]; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target[0]; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target[1]; });
}

function redrawSite(site) {
  site
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d[0]; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d[1]; });
}

</script>
```

Comment: Please don't add unnecessary things to your question.

Comment: @G_V, Sorry but I have to do it otherwise there was a warning say 'too many codes, need to add more words' which prevented me from submitting my question

Comment: Do we really need to see all this CSS and styling related stuff though? Also you should reread your question, it doesn't make sense in English, like it's missing words. A lot of people on SO automatically skip questions that aren't very clearly worded in what the actual question is.